# How to animate input box from page center to the top of the page on input focus in css?

Tags: html, css, input, transform

I think this is very simple, but I'm not sure how it's implemented. So let's say I have an input field that is originally centered to the page (vertically & horizontally). However, I want to animate the input box to the top of the page when the user starts typing, how would this be implemented? My initial thought would be to assign the `top:0` and transform it on focus. Is it more complex than that?

Please enlighten me.

```css
input.input-student-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  padding: 27px 145px 27px 38px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.02), 0 6px 6px rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.23);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  &:focus {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
.txt {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    top: 200px;
    transition: top 0.4s;
}

.txt:focus{
    top:0;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5y5x2a0L/)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Just put `top:0` in a `:focus` style:

```
input.input-student-search:focus {
  top:0;
}
```

```css
input.input-student-search {
  background-color:#AAA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  padding: 27px 145px 27px 38px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.02), 0 6px 6px rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.23);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  transition:top 1s linear; 
}
input.input-student-search:focus {
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-student-search" type="text"/>
```

Comment: exactly, but how would i give some animation that it moves smoothly?